# Compiling my own executable file with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, exe

I want to compile my own executable with Nodejs, without using external packages such as pkg. Could somebody tell me how I would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking myself and have come up with little except for this project: https://bellard.org/quickjs/

I managed to get it working on my mac, but I caution advice as this is still very early stage. I quickly ran into compiler errors, I have no idea how to compile for other platforms, the project hasn't seen updates in a while, and the framework is a completely new one, so you gotta a learning curve.

On the plus side, the executable was only kilobytes in size and the startup speed was instant. I hope the work on this continues as I'm excited about where it could go.